# How to read a hex data from a text file in C

Tags: c, text, hex, can-bus

I am trying to read a text file with CAN data, the format the file is something like this :

> XL_CAN_EV_TAG_RX_OK ch:0 t=51165282304 id:98FF5C80 dlc:7
>   000000040000E0    XL_CAN_EV_TAG_RX_OK ch:0 t=51172728832 id:98FF1480
>   dlc:7 FFFFFFAD7C1CFF    XL_CAN_EV_TAG_RX_OK ch:0 t=51173007360
>   id:98FF1080 dlc:7 FFFFE30C0E01FF    XL_CAN_EV_TAG_RX_OK ch:0
>   t=51173285888 id:98FF1180 dlc:7 FFFF9706FEFFFB    XL_CAN_EV_TAG_RX_OK
>   ch:0 t=51173564416 id:98FF1280 dlc:7 FFFF9706FEFFFB

I have to read the CANid and the the CANDATA as seen above, I managed to read the CANID using the :

```
unsigned int hex = 0; 
fscanf(fr, "%X", &hex); 
printf(" %X ", hex);
```

I use the c = fgetc(fr); till the c reads the second ":" and hex reads the canid fine.

But, when I have to read the data using the same code "fscaf", it only reads the last 7 data for example ,I get results like this :

`40000e0
D7C1CFF 
C0E01FF 
6FEFFFB 
6FEFFFB`

This is the problem. The alternative i found is to read it as char.

If i use the getc to read, I get the data in char format, I am not sure how to convert that to a hex and also it reads each letter separately and I have to combine them and then convert it into an int type (hex) specifically and send it to a array, something like this:

> data[0]=FF; data[1]=FF; data[2]=FF; data[3]=AD; data[4]=7C;
>   data[5]=1C; data[6]=FF;

I have been stuck here since two days, googled everything and tried everything, nothing seems to work, can you please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading an `unsigned int` and storing into an `unsigned int`. `unsigned int` is 32 bits, your hex values are 7 bytes or 56 bits long. You need a 64 bits container for those. You'll want to use `unsigned long long int` and read/write them with `%llX`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I am now able to get the whole data, do you have an idea how do i convert or split that into an array ?

Comment: @Akash you want to divide the 7 bytes, most significant to least significant so you want to use a bit shift like this: `data[i] = (hex >> (8*(6-i))) & 0xFF`. This will give you `data[0] = (hex >> 48) & 0xFF`, `data[1] = (hex >> 40) & 0xFF`, and so on, with the last one being `data[6] = hex & 0xFF` (the shift is value is `0` for the last one). You can do that with a `for` loop or write them down manually. The `& 0xFF` is there to select only the byte you want and discard the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, you saved my life... !! It worked.. :)